# Vertica convert date format

Tags: sql, vertica

In **MSSQL** we can convert the date format into the format we wanted.

## for example :

```
convert(char(10),column_name , 120)
```

in vertica database can we do the same?

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,120)
```

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TO_CHAR.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Functions%7CFormatting%2520Functions%7C_____2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select current_timestamp::varchar ;
```

Or this?

```
select left(current_timestamp::varchar, 10) ;
```

A look to the [Data Type Coercion](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/DataTypes/DataTypeCoercion.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Data%2520Types%7C_____7) section and the [Data Type Coercion Chart](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/DataTypes/DataTypeCoercionChart.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Data%2520Types%7C_____8) in the standard documentation would probably help...

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to MS SQL, Vertica has the three classic ANSI data types to store the element of time:

1. `DATE`, which is exactly at day precision; default format usually YYYY-MM-DD.
2. `TIME`, which is usually formatted as HH24:MI:SS, plus optionally up to 6 digits for the fraction of the second
3. `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMPZ` for the whole timestamp; `TIMESTAMPZ` includes the time zone, the other not. And the default format for the `TIMESTAMP` is YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US, for example: 2017-01-29 07:45:44.896498.

Any of these input types can be formatted as you like using the same function that comes from Oracle: TO_CHAR.

MSSQL's not so self explanatory format code 120, corresponds to this format string: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.

And this is how you use it; I'm usig CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as input, to show what it makes out of it:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIME     ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS from_tm
, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE     ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS from_dt
, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS from_ts
;

       from_tm       |       from_dt       |       from_ts
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2017-01-29 07:54:05 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 07:54:05
```

The nice thing here is that this TO_CHAR() function is very common in many databases, and other SQL coders will easily understand what's happening in this bit of code.

Happy Playing

Marco the Sane

Answer (score 0):

**Also you can get this like this :**

```
select getdate()::date;
```

There are many ways to convert date types , see documentation bellow for more details 
[Vertica Date Transformation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/DATE_TRUNC.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Functions%7CDate%252FTime%2520Functions%7C_____10)