# Converting Timestamp to Date in Snowflake

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working within Snowflake and have a column with a timestamp format like this:

`timestamp`

```
2021-12-13T21:52:58.656216349+0000
2021-12-13T18:22:01.194783523+0000
2021-12-13T21:03:55.224874997+0000
2021-12-13T21:02:37.075422427+0000
2021-12-13T15:54:26.268433672+0000
```

my desired output is in a format with:

```
2021-12-13
```

Searching from past questions, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68475840/9840684) and attempted to modify it for my use by:

```
SELECT
    timestamp AS original_ts,
    to_timestamp(REPLACE(REPLACE(timestamp,'T',' '),'+',''),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS modified_ts 
FROM
    table
```

but get the following error:

`Can't parse '2022-01-26 00:06:11.1851022090000' as timestamp with format 'YYYY-MM-DD'`

How can I resolve this error and format the timestamp column into a more familiar date column ignoring the time entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use [`TO_DATE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) here along with `LEFT`:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(LEFT(timestamp, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS modified_ts
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that if you don't require a bona fide date, but rather just a date string, then `LEFT(timestamp, 10)` alone should suffice.

Comment: That's it! Simpler than I thought! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DATE_TRUNC function then you don’t need to worry about the format of the source column, and therefore you don’t need the LEFT function - assuming it is a date or timestamp column